# Compare text input to pass code Android

Tags: android

I'm making a loyalty card app and simply want the app to open a new window when one of the loyalty stamps is clicked. This I have achieved, but then I want it to ask for a pass code to make the loyalty stamp official, I have got to the point where it opens a new window and asks for the code but then when I press the button it does nothing. I did have it so that when I pressed the button it sent me back to the previous activity, but now it won't even do that.

Here's the activity that asks for the code:

```
package com.example.reloadgamesapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class LoyaltyWindow extends Activity implements OnClickListener, TextWatcher {

private EditText passcode;
String unlock_code = "supern1nja";
int unlock = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.loyalty_window);

    //get Button reference
    View v = findViewById(R.id.code_button);
    //set event listener
    v.setOnClickListener(this); 

    passcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passcode);
    passcode.addTextChangedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(arg0.getId() == R.id.code_button && unlock != 0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        //start
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    String passString = passcode.getText().toString();

    if(passString == unlock_code) {
        unlock = 1;
    } else {
        unlock = 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Any help will be much appreciated, I'm very new to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Strings are compared using `passString.equals(unlock_code)`. So your code should look like this:

```
if(passString.equals(unlock_code)) {
    unlock = 1;
} else {
    unlock = 0;
}
```

But I have to warn you that putting your `unlock_code` in the source code of the app makes it really simple to find it out. Anyone with the right tools can decompile the APK to Java source code.

You can go back to the previous activity using `finish()`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help though sadly this didn't seem to change anything, when I hit the submit button to enter the passcode nothing happens. It doesn't seem to be actually retrieving the code and checking it.